# javascript sometimes CET sometimes CEST

Tags: javascript, date

I've one script where I create two Date instance, the first return the date in CET offset timestamp and the second in CEST. I can't understand why.

```
var start_date = new Date(2014, 1, 26, 12, 0 , 0, 0);   
var first_start_date = new Date(2014, 3, 1, 12, 0 , 0, 0);
```

return: Wed Feb 26 2014 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET) Tue Apr 01 2014 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)

I've also create a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/v9hd4/)

Comment: On Feb 26th, daylight savings time isn't in effect. On Apr 1st, it is.

Comment: That's not a timezone, that's daylight saving time.

Comment: ok! Can I force the Date object to return only in GMT?

Comment: It already is in GMT.... Do you just want to strip the last bit from you string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to [DST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

Also, see that [CEST is Central European Summer Time](https://www.google.com/search?q=cest+cet).

Comment: so how am I suppose to solve this issue and always return in CST?

Answer (score 1):

It's just because April 1 is in Daylight Savings time (starts March 9th in the US this year), and February 26th is not in Daylight Savings time.